# Used a roller on metallic paint and it dried bumpy is there a fix to smooting it out after first coat has dried

Tags: painting

Paint mistake with metallic paint using a roller dried bumpy is there a fix to smooth it out before applying second coat

Comment: Sandpaper ... ...

Comment: concur .........

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't use a microfiber roller to do the painting. A normal roller would put too much paint on the wall and you'd get that "orange peel" effect. Even with the right roller, you still have to go over the area while the paint is still wet a few times and do small areas at a time.

To remove the bumps, get some sandpaper and go to work. You want the walls smooth so use a fine grit so start out with and depending on the size of the bumps, you might need a scraper to remove large ones.

Answer (score -1):

Knock down the bumps with a fine sandpaper and get it to where you are happy.

Add some [Floetrol](https://www.ppgpaints.com/products/specialty/flood-floetrol-latex-based-paint-additive) to your paint, it'll extend dry time and act as a leveling agent which should eliminate brush and roller marks.

> FLOOD® FLOETROL® Latex-Based Paint Additive is a latex paint additive that makes interior and exterior latex or acrylic paint flow and level like oil-based paints while compensating for the adverse effects that weather and surface conditions have on paints and primers.

Also, make sure you're using a microfiber cover, preferably an 1/8" nap.

When you're rolling paint you have to keep a wet edge, don't let it sit for too long or you'll end up with stripes and the paint will tack up making it harder to roll.